# How to detach a partition from a table and attach it to another in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I have a table with huge data( say millions of records, its just a case study though!) of 5 years, with a partition for each year. Now i would want to retain the last 2 years data, and transfer the rest of the 3 year data to a new table called archive?

What would be the Ideal method, with minimal down time and high performance?

Comment: for close voters: this is a question about data manipulation. In the most cases DBA won't involve in this. The db programmer must do it itself.

Comment: @FlorinGhita [dba.se] deals with more than DBA stuff ;) Though I wasn't the one to VtC

Comment: @Sathya I understand. But I think this question fits ok here, on stackoverflow. Probably it is fine for dba.stackexchange.com, but it is also ok here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
alter table exchange partition
```

is the answer. This command exange the segment of a partition with the segment of a table. It is at light speed because it does only some reference interchages.
So, you need some temp tables, because AFAIK you can't exchange them directly.

Something like:

```
create table tmp_table(same columns);
Add partition p_2011 in table ARCH_TABLE;

ALTER TABLE CURR_TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION P_2011 WITH TABLE tmp_table;
ALTER TABLE ARCH_TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION P_2011 WITH TABLE tmp_table;
```

Please test test your code before run.

Comment: thanks for the the Response, I would want to know if the destination table arch is necessary to have the partition.

Comment: Yes is absolutely necessary. It is the second line in the example(add partition). And I recommend you that the tables should have same partitions, whith same ranges.

Comment: The destination Table does not necessarily have the Partition.

Comment: So, please add it. The `exchange` command won't work without it. `Alter table add partiton` is the command.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is partitioned by RANGE, INTERVAL or HASH partitioning, you shouldn't have significant problems by using partition exchange:

```
ALTER TABLE <partitioned table>
EXCHANGE PARTITION <partition name>
WITH TABLE <non-partitioned temporary table>
```

With optional directives `WITHOUT VALIDATION` and `UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES` at end.

However keep in mind that if you want to move partitions of tables that either use PARTITION BY REFERENCE or parent tables that have data used by reference in tables partitioned by reference, you must use Oracle Server version **12.1** or later. In Oracle Server 11gR2 partition exchange for tables partitioned by reference, is not exactly supported and you will stumble upon date/reference integrity errors

```
ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys
ORA-14128: FOREIGN KEY constraint mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
```

or if you want to disable or remove affected constraints

```
ORA-14650: operation not supported for reference-partitioned tables
```

Which if you can't/won't upgrade to Oracle Server 12.1+, give you the copying data to archive tables with deleting from original tables as the only option.